# PHP Web Page Parsing into MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got a question here.
I am parsing webpages and here is my current code:

```
<?php
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('siteone.htm');

// //Dates
echo 'Dates:<br />';
foreach($html->find('div.collectionLog td') as $e) {
    $text = $e->innertext;
    $string = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$text);
    echo $string . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="data-container collectionLog">
    <h3>Collection Log</h3>
    <div id="lcLoanPerf2">

        <table id="lcLoanPerfTable2" class="plain-table">
            <tbody>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>
```

Now what I want to do is insert information into the database. I know how to do that easily but I am confused in how to make it so it inserts the td time and the td with no class/id in the same row.
So basically I want:

```
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
```

into one row, basically `<tr class="">` in it's own MYSQL row.
Sorry if I am not being descriptive enough, first time and it is hard to explain this.
If you don't understand, please let me know. Just trying to make this possible.

Thanks,
Gamemann

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [Symfony DOM Crawler](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler) (with the [Symfony CSS Selector](https://github.com/symfony/CssSelector)) for parsing websites, instead of regular expressions.

Using the Symfony DOM Crawler, see this working example:

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$crawler = new Crawler('<div class="data-container collectionLog">
    <h3>Collection Log</h3>
    <div id="lcLoanPerf2">

        <table id="lcLoanPerfTable2" class="plain-table">
            <tbody>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="">
                    <td class="time">**/**/**</td>
                    <td>***********</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>');

$tfList = $crawler->filter('#lcLoanPerfTable2 tr td');

foreach($tfList AS $list) {
    foreach($list->childNodes as $node) {
        var_dump($node->wholeText);
    }
}
```

This way you have the `td`-list and in the `foreach`, the (in this case two) `td` elements. You can save those to a database or do whatever you want with it.